# Full-Screen Exclusive Mode Crashes when Click on Menu Bar

Tags: java, swing, jframe, fullscreen, jmenu

I am trying to use Full-Screen Exclusive Mode for a game written in Java. I successfully got the game to run in Full-Screen Exclusive Mode. However, the problem I am having is: As soon as I click on the Menu Bar at the top of the main frame, the screen goes black; it seems everything just crashes.

I am not sure what is wrong because I followed the instructions provided by Oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/

The first code segment below is where the program starts and checks if Full-Screen Exclusive Mode is supported. If it is supported, then enter the mode.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    GraphicsEnvironment graphhicsEnv = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice device = graphhicsEnv.getDefaultScreenDevice();

    GraphicsConfiguration graphicsConfiguration = device.getDefaultConfiguration();

    final Frame frame = new Frame(graphicsConfiguration);

    if (device.isFullScreenSupported())
    {
        try
        {   
            // Turn on Full-Screen Exclusive Mode on the main frame.
            device.setFullScreenWindow(frame);

            frame.createBufferStrategy(2);
            BufferStrategy bufferStrategy = frame.getBufferStrategy();

            frame.requestFocus();

            while (true)
            {
                Graphics g = bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();

                frame.paint(g);

                g.dispose();

                bufferStrategy.show();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { e.printStackTrace(); }
        finally
        { device.setFullScreenWindow(null); }
    }
```

}

The code segment below is the Constructor of class Frame, which implements the main frame of the program:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame
{
// The content panel of the main frame.
private Panel panel;



/*************************************
 * Default constructor of class Frame.
 *************************************/
public Frame (GraphicsConfiguration graphicsConfiguration)
{
    super("Chaos", graphicsConfiguration);

    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    this.setResizable(false);

    this.setIgnoreRepaint(true);

    this.setUndecorated(true);

    // Create the content panel for this main frame.
    this.panel = new OceanPanel();

    // Add the content panel just created to the main frame.
    this.setContentPane(this.panel);

    // Set the menu bar.
    this.setMenuBar();
}
```

Finally, the code segment below is the implementation of method setMenuBar(), which adds all the menu items.

```
private void setMenuBar()
{
    // Create a the menu bar.
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

    // Create the menus.
    JMenu menu   = new JMenu("Menu");
    JMenu weapon = new JMenu("Weapon");

    // Create the menu items for the menu "Stuff".
    JMenuItem waves = new JMenuItem("Ocean Waves");
    JMenuItem quit  = new JMenuItem("Quit");

    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();

    // Create menu items for the menu "Weapon".
    final JRadioButtonMenuItem none   = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("None");
    final JRadioButtonMenuItem pistol = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Pistol");



    /********************************************************
     * Add action listener for each item in the menu "Stuff".
     ********************************************************/

    // 
    waves.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
                                {
                                    // Toggle the ocean waves on and off.
                                    //panel.toggleWaves();
                                }
                            });

    // 
    quit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                           {
                                @Override
                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
                                {
                                    setVisible(false);
                                    dispose();
                                    System.exit(0);
                                }
                           });



    /*********************************************************
     * Add action listener for each item in the menu "Weapon".
     *********************************************************/

    // "none" menu item hides the weapon.
    none.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                           {
                                @Override
                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
                                {
                                    panel.setWeapon(Panel.WEAPON_TYPE.NONE);
                                }
                           });


    pistol.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                           {
                                @Override
                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
                                {
                                    panel.setWeapon(Panel.WEAPON_TYPE.PISTOL);
                                }
                           });


    // ------------------------
    // Add everything together.
    // ------------------------
    menu.add(waves);
    menu.add(quit);

    group.add(none);
    group.add(pistol);

    weapon.add(none);
    weapon.add(pistol);

    menuBar.add(menu);
    menuBar.add(weapon);

    // Add the menu bar just created into the main frame.
    this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
}
```

The program can run in Full-Screen Exclusive Mode. However, as soon as I click on the menu bar, everything crashes, and the screen just went black. I could not take back control of the program; nothing on the keyboard works. I had to force shutdown the computer by holding the power button.

I am working on a MacBook Pro Mid 2012 and use Java version 1.8.

Comment: You can't use swing controls with a BufferStragey, they have different painting requirements

Comment: @MadProgrammer, can you elaborate more on your comments? You are saying that I cannot use JMenu, JMenuBar, and JMenuItem with BufferStrategy? What is your suggestion to make this work? I never saw it mentioned anywhere that we cannot use swing controls with BufferStrategy. Can you provide a source?

Comment: Swing uses it's own "passive" rendering engine, but know you've taken control over it using an active painting approach, they are going to conflict